# How to cast from int to long long int*?

Tags: c++, casting

I tried this:

```
request.DeviceID = (long long int *)&(DeviceID);
request.ProdReqID = (long long int *)&(ProdReqID);
```

but when I do:

```
cout << "DEVICE ID: " << request.DeviceID << " " << request.ProdReqID << " " << endl;
cout << "DEVICE ID: " << &request.DeviceID << " " << &request.ProdReqID << " " << endl;
```

I get:

> DEVICE ID: 0xfffa9bf0 0xfffa9bf4 
>   DEVICE ID: 0xfffa9bd4 0xfffa9bd8

I really don't know if this is working or not.  I expected to see a print out of the actual numbers...

Comment: You can't change the type of `DeviceID` or `ProdReqID` in runtime like you appear to be trying to...

Comment: I had a mistake on the type it is long long int*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing DeviceID and ProdReqID parameters from `int` to `LONG64` and then doing:

```
request.DeviceID = &(DeviceID);
request.ProdReqID = &(ProdReqID);
```

Answer (score 3):

If `DeviceID` and `ProdReqID` is `int`, and `request.DeviceID` and `request.ProdReqID` is `long long int`, then do:

```
request.DeviceID = (long long int)DeviceID;
request.ProdReqID = (long long int)ProdReqID;
```

using a cast or even:

```
request.DeviceID = DeviceID;
request.ProdReqID = ProdReqID;
```

using a type promotion.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what the types actually are, but assuming `int DeviceID` and `long long int Request::DeviceID` (as implied by the original title, before it was changed), the conversion happens implicitly:

```
request.DeviceID = DeviceID;
```

However, it appears from your code that `request.DeviceID` is a pointer. This is almost certainly not what you want, but if it is, then it will need a value of the correct type to point to, e.g.

```
long long int DeviceIDValue = DeviceID;
request.DeviceID = &DeviceIDValue;
```

You can access the value by dereferencing the pointer:

```
cout << "DEVICE ID: " << *request.DeviceID << " " << *request.ProdReqID << " " << endl;
```

The dodgy casts in your code simply bypass type checking and create an invalid pointer to the wrong type. If (as you should) you use C++-style casts rather than the utterly evil C-style cast, then you'd have to write `reinterpret_cast`, which should ring a very loud alarm bell - that conversion is not valid.

Comment: Oh, I used what you have in the cout and left the rest the same, but I get a huge number on the print out: DEVICE ID: 21474836482 8589934597.  I should only get 2 and 5.

Comment: @O.O: Yes, I've just been updating my answer to explain that the pointer conversion is invalid. Are you sure you want to use pointers at all? It looks like you're doing something very strange.

Comment: I really have no control over 'request' because that was generated by gSOAP, it is the proxy class.  I am not a c++ developer and I am debugging someone elses code.  So, I believe you that it is strange.

Comment: @O.O: OK. If it really is a pointer, then you'll need a value, somewhere, of the correct type for the pointer to point to; and you'll need to make sure that value doesn't go out of scope as long as the pointer might be used.